# Can not get facebook page token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am currently creating a website that need to create post on a Facebook page.

I made a signin button to request a page token but the documentation is not easy to understand. I am blocked on this request:

```
ApiCall::callAPI("GET", "https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/" . $data["user_id"] . "/accounts?access_token=" . $data["secret_token"])
```

The function is home made, it's a simple curl call.
From this, I get the error:

> (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: accounts

But if I do the exact same request in the explorer (developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) it works. So it shall not be a problem from the call.

Also, it shall give me a non-expiring token but by the explorer it is still a 3 month token.

Anyone is aware about the procedure?
Thanks!

Comment: The alias is the part directly after the API version - like a user id or page name. If the API complains about `accounts` as an _alias_ here, then the most likely explanation is that `$data["user_id"]` which you tried to insert into the URL there, was actually empty/not set.

Comment: Ok thank you, I am checking this

Comment: Ok thank you, it was that, I didn't handled correctly thoses variables...
Anyway the other problem remain, the token expire in 3 month but it shouldn't according to the doc

Comment: Probably because the user token you are using there, is short-lived, and not extended.